# Leibniz rule - problem with one of the parts of the function when it is not defined at some x

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, leibniz-integral-rule

I'm having trouble with solving the following integral with Leibniz's rule.

> $F\left(\alpha\right) = \int_{0}^{π}{\frac{\ln{\left(1+\sin{\alpha}\cos{\alpha}\right)}}{\cos{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x} $

The first thing I did was to find the derivative in respect to the parameter α and also taking care of the critical x=π/2 by splitting the integral in two parts with two limits.

**My question is: is it even allowed to split the integral like that and also using Leibniz's formula, when we have a point where the integrand goes to infinity?**

**If not, then what's the best method to use here?**

Comment: First of all, $ \ln{\left(1+\sin{\alpha}\cos{\alpha}\right)} $ is a constant, so you may get it outside of the integral. The problem would then be integrating $ \sec{x} $ over $ \left[0,\pi\right] $, which is not a possible thing since $ \sec{x} $ has a singularity at $ x=\frac{\pi}{2} $. Your integral does not converge.

Comment: Oh, I haven't noticed that I can move the natural log outside! Thank you!

Comment: @Wolfcho Before you do that, you should probably go back and make sure you wrote the problem down correctly. I suspect one of those $\alpha$'s is supposed to be an $x$.